# Struts2 error on startup

Tags: java, struts2

Hi this is my second post regarding getting struts2 to work. I have downloaded and installed the minimum dependency pack from apache struts which includes

commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.6.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
ognl-3.1.15.jar
struts2-core-2.5.13.jar

All of which have been added to my build path in eclipse oxygen. I have tomcat 7 and 8.5 installed on my local machine alongside Java 9.

I have updated the filter dispatcher to the newest statement

org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

I am getting the following error after startup, anyone got any ideas pls!!!

```
INFO: Server startup in 2389 ms
Nov 02, 2017 2:15:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Hello]     threw exception
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3:     jar:file:\C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\Hello\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-    core-2.5.13.jar
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.File.toPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JarEntryRevision.needsReloading(JarEntryRevision.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.fileNeedsReloading(DefaultFileManager.java:62)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:425)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.needReloadContainerProviders(ConfigurationManager.java:208)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:174)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:960)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeStaticResourceRequest(ExecuteOperations.java:59)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which will be fixed in Struts 2.5.14. See also [this jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4869) and [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/struts/pull/172)